# Gnome extension not displayed

Tags: nvidia, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I am using Ubuntu 19.10 and wanted to install and extension on it.
That extension is `nvidia-gpu-stats tool` which I installed from the Ubuntu Software Center application.

Apparently, it is supposed to look something like this:-

[image]

However, In my case there is nothing on the extension bar on the top right corner.
Though I don't think I have any other extensions, the slack logo, and the sticky notes logo is always present in that bar.

So why isn't my extension showing up? I tried opening the drop-down on the bar and it has only the night light and wifi and account options there (no sign of my extension)

So how do I fix this? 
I checked the extension settings and made sure it was on and even tried fiddling with it, but to no avail.

**EDIT:-**
after doing `gsettings get org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions` I got this:-

```
ns
@as []
```

Comment: @pomsky I had installed it long before. But it has never worked. So it must be like a 100+ reboots...

Comment: Also `apt policy nvidia-settings`. Anyway this extension does not *officially* support the GNOME Shell version that comes with 19.10.

Comment: @pomsky apparently it works for other 20 people on 18.04 LTS...

Comment: But yours is **19.10**, right?

Comment: Well it works in 19.04 but funnily enough, another user reviewed it negatively with the exact same spec `not work in Ubuntu 19.10 , graphic card GTX 1050 ti` so guess it doesn't work...

Comment: It hasn't been updated in last couple of years or so, last supported GNOME Shell version is 3.28 (the one in Ubuntu 18.04, Ubuntu 19.10 has 3.34), so not really surprising.

Comment: is downgrading GNOME a good idea? or is it just a waste of time?